# Cypress - Call custom command in BeforeEach Hook

Tags: javascript, command, hook, cypress

Can anyone assist in following case:
Wrote several custom commands and add them into beforeEach Hook. Only one has 3 variables in it, and can no call that function. Can someone help to fix this, it looks like small issue, but not logical one to me.

Imported commands into support/index.js (already for older functions/commands

So. command looks:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('mockChosenData', (partURL, mockFile, aliasName) => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route(partURL, mockFile).as(aliasName);
});
```

Calling command in test:

```
cy.mockChosenData(
  'partURL_value',
  'fixture:file.json',
  'aliasName_Value',
);
```

And get this when run test in beforeEach hook:

[image]

Support/index.js file

[image]

Comment: Tried your command and it worked fine for me. Can you share your 'support/index.js' and 'support/commands.js' files? Maybe the issue is in how to define the command

Comment: Added support/index.js file into question

Regarding command, it is shown in question how does it looks

Comment: @AnastasiiaSolop I suppose that issue is because used in beforeEach hook, but do not know solution how to use it

Comment: All commands from support/index.js are loaded before any test files are evaluated, as written in the docs. For me your example works perfectly fine, so the issue must be either in the test file or in support/commands.js file.

Comment: @AnastasiiaSolop What could be? Not have any idea. Wrote in question body how command looks and how I am calling it in test. Any suggestion?

Comment: It could be anything, even a simple typo in defining your other commands that break the parsing of the file or the test file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223083/discussion-between-anastasiia-solop-and-zoran).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue is inside your `support/commands.js` file. Review it for typos and possible parsing errors. Make sure you do not define commands inside of other commands by mistake.